# Can you give an example of a good command to start with if you are new to Dragon Advanced Scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I'm especially interested in this use case as it applies to automating Epic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it for Epic I would start with something simple that you know you will use every day, like automating pulling in a most used progress note template.  You could call the script "open progress note".

```
SendDragonKeys "{Ctrl+Shift+n}"
Wait 1.5
SendDragonKeys ".nameofmytemplate"
SendDragonKeys "{Enter}"
```

The most important thing is getting your feet wet with something that will give you immediate results and value, but not be overly complex or subject to failure.